# Local Photo Gallery

Tags: java, android, ios, tabris

Is there a way to get Photos from the Gallery of the Device with Tabris? I know that it wasnt possible like half a year ago, maybe there is a way now? Couldnt find any information on the tabris homepage.

Comment: It been possible for a long time, look at [Assets Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/index.html) for iOS, not sure whether tabris supports is.

Comment: thx for your answer, but looking for a way in Tabris right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just added that functionality to Tabris.
It should come with the next release.
You  can take a look at the CameraDemo here: https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-demos/blob/master/com.eclipsesource.tabris.demos/src/com/eclipsesource/tabris/demos/entrypoints/CameraDemo.java#L179